# Verificar se tenho dados na query, ao dar o next ou prior

Tags: mysql, delphi, query, firedac

Eu tenho uma query no delphi, onde eu dou o comando next e prior, só que eu não consigo verificar se é meu primeiro ou ultimo registro, o que eu quero especificamente é, ao apertar o botão next, verificar se é meu ultimo item da lista e vice-versa; Tô usando o componete FDquery, TdataSource e o mysql e firedac,
Aproveitando o gancho, eu queria saber como eu faço pra verificar se, no momento que eu for cadastrar um novo dado, se esse dado já foi cadastrado, obrigado e desculpe se ficou confuso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para saber se é o primeiro ou ultimo registo é usar as funçoes `dataset.bof` (*Begin Of File*, começo do arquivo) e `dataset.eof` (*End Of File*, fim do arquivo)

Por isso tipicamente o loop de um dataset se faz assim:

```
dataset.first;
while not dataset.eof do
begin
   //
   dataset.next;
end;
```

Comment: Obrigado funcionou, e você poderia me ajudar com a segunda parte? Quando eu for cadastrar um novo dado, como eu faço para verificar se já existe no meu banco?

Comment: isso mais vale criar outro post. Depende da sua tabela, chaves primarias, etc....